# How to load chat history on top of recycler view android

Tags: android, performance, listview

Hi I am developing a chat application like whatsapp. I have to load the chat history from the api when user scrolls down like in whatsapp. I get the data and set it to the adapter. But the history is loading at the bottom of recycler view. I need to add it on top for every scroll. This is my code. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
                              if (Status.equals("1")) {
                                historyList = resp.getHistory();
                                Log.i("history size",String.valueOf(resp.getHistory().size()));
                                String historysize = String.valueOf(resp.getHistory().size());
                                Message message = new Message();
                                for (int i = 0; i < resp.getHistory().size(); i++) {
                                    String fromusertoken = String.valueOf(resp.getHistory().get(i).getFromUserToken());
                                    String txtmsg = resp.getHistory().get(i).getMessage();
                                    String username = String.valueOf(resp.getHistory().get(i).getFromUserName());

                                    if (fromusertoken.equals(user_token)) {
                                        Message messages = new Message();
                                        messages.setUser_token(fromusertoken);
                                        messages.setUsername(username);
                                        messages.setIsMine(true);
                                        messages.setMessage(txtmsg);
                                        messageAdapter.add(messages);

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        Message messages = new Message();
                                        messages.setUser_token(fromusertoken);
                                        messages.setUsername(username);
                                        messages.setIsMine(false);
                                        messages.setMessage(txtmsg);
                                        messageAdapter.add(messages);
                                    }
                                }

                                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                onItemsLoadComplete();

                                Toast.makeText(Single_chat.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Single_chat.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(Single_chat.this, "No Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
```

Comment: add history data in 0th index

Comment: You should reduce your code sample to a minimum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

I changed the list in adapter as `messagelist.add(0,message)`. It worked.

```
public void add(Message message) {
    messageList.add(0,message);
    notifyItemInserted(messageList.size() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set the item on top by editing the adapter class not the activity. We have to add the item list like `messagelist.add(0,message)`. Now only i found. For your regular chat you have to add as normal like `messagelist.add(message)`. This will add the item at bottom. Hope this will be useful for others.

```
public void add(Message message) {
    messageList.add(message);
    notifyItemInserted(messageList.size() - 1);
}
public void add(int i,Message message) {
    messageList.add(0,message);
    notifyItemInserted(messageList.size() - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert the history message at the index 0

`messageAdapter.add(0,messages);`

every iteration it will replace the first message by the last inserted message.

Answer (score 0):

```
chatHistoyList.add(adapter.getCurrentChatList());

adapter.setData(chatHistoryList);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//This method has to be in adapter
public List<Chat> getCurrentChatList() {
         return currentChatList;
}
```